# Connect several PC to the same Xamarin Mac Agent on Apple

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

Any info on this:

Just to clarify, with Xamarin 4, The Xamarin Mac Agent supports multiple instances of Visual Studio to connect to one Apple Mac machine for build.
But: can you connect 2 PC to the one Apple mac for build?

Comment: As soon as that link dies, this question (and any possible answers) is worthless.

Comment: Do you mean MAC address (i.e. the ethernet address of a network card) or a Macintosh computer (one made by Apple)?

Comment: I'll add a comment since I can't post an answer. Yes, two Visual Studio instances (possibly on two different Windows machines) can both connect to the same Mac host with the Xamarin 4 upgrade. However, I'm not sure if you can or would want to both try compiling at the same time. I would think the mono paths would be the same. It *might* work if you connected as different users, but I'm not sure if those are user or system folders. I would just coordinate builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got info on twitter from @JamesMontemagno

Its multiple VS to 1 Mac. It is based on logged in users

From: https://twitter.com/JamesMontemagno/status/669940265101070336?s=09